# Dynamically added Text Boxes not accessible / not added in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, asp-classic

I wrote a small code to make the textbox addition on the page dynamically. And was able to do it.

But the problem arised when i tried to access those elements in the DOM for addition into database. Though the textboxes were on the Screen and also were shown in F12(Inspect Element) but when i tried for view source surprisingly they were not there in the source.

So to check its validity i added a hardcoded textbox in the Screen and again went to check the same. This time the hardcoded textbox was shown in the screen but again the dynamically added were not.

This is causing me problems because when i trying to save the values of those boxes i am not able to save them in DB.

Here is my code.

```
   <html>
<body>

<div id ='div1' style="margin-bottom:6px;">
<input name="cust_name_a" id="cust_name_a" value="" type="text" size="0" class="FormTextField" maxlength="6" title="">
    <input name="cust_name_hid" id="cust_name_hid" value="">

</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Change link</button>

<script>
var i = 0;
function myFunction() {
//var p_strContents = '<input name="cust_name_0" id="cust_name_0" value="" //type="text" size="0" class="FormTextField" maxlength="6" title="">';
var p_strContents = document.createElement('input');
p_strContents.setAttribute('type', 'text');          
p_strContents.setAttribute('name', 'cust_name_' + i);
p_strContents.setAttribute('id', 'cust_name_'+i);
p_strContents.setAttribute('value', '');
p_strContents.setAttribute('size', '0');
p_strContents.setAttribute('class', 'FormTextField');
p_strContents.setAttribute('maxlength', '6');
p_strContents.setAttribute('title', '');
document.getElementById('div1').appendChild(p_strContents);
i++;
document.getElementById('cust_name_hid').value= i;
    }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

You could check the same by running code adding the textboxes by button click and the checking both F12 and View Source.

Added and edited code

```
Dim counter, inputval , i 
i=0
counter = Request.Form("cust_name_hid")


Do While i>10
   inputval = Request.Form("cust_name_" & i)
    'Insert Code 
  i = i+1
Loop
```

Comment: Which browser you are using? Try hitting the refresh button in your F12 -> debugger window and check whether you are able to see the dynamic DOM...

Comment: I [can't reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/w79ae3mp/) your issue. If you're viewing the page source code (CTRL + U), the you can't see dynamic elements, it's the original code loaded from a server, it is not updated.

Comment: I tried your code in chrome and I am able to see the DOM of dynamic controls.

Comment: Yes i debugged it i am able to get those even on ding F12 working fine just when i try to acces those elements from my ASP page they wont since in source page they are not shown.  Try run the code and do F12 and source u will understand

Comment: yes u will be thats what i said but now go to chrome do view source do u see the dynamic elements???

Comment: problem is happening when on another 2nd button click i am trying to save these into database they wont return any value ie not have any value

Comment: how are you trying to access the dynamic DOM elements during save? Can you share that code?

Comment: Maybe you'd need a `form` for the `input`s, currently they are appended to a `div`.

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh code added for u both please check i havent added the insert query it will be straight INSERT into like that. please help

Answer (score 0):

Your asp loop is not correct:

```
Do While i>10
  inputval = Request.Form("cust_name_" & i) 
  i = i+1
Loop
```

Do while `i` is larger than 10. It's never larger than 10 in your code.

```
Do While i<10
```

This will work better I'm sure.